# UISearchBar works only after an UIAlertView show

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a search bar in my app but it only works (appear what I digit) after a `alertViewShow`. I have implemented all the methods from the delegate: `shouldChangeTextInRange`, `searchBarShouldEndEditing`, `searchBarShouldBeginEditing`

The status bar is ok... Any idea about what is going wrong?

```
  -(IBAction)btnSearchClick:(id)sender {
      if (!searchBarVisivel) {
          [searchBar setHidden:NO];
          searchBarVisivel = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        searchBarVisivel = NO;
        [searchBar setHidden:YES];
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

//the search bar appears, when I touch in text field of search bar the keyboard appears, but when I digit...nothing...

when I call other event that alert a message...the search bar works after...

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                 message:@"Alert message"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Não"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Sim",nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: I have edited the question, see pls and vote up.

Comment: Did you try checking what happens with breakpoints and the values of searchBarVisivel etc... ??

Comment: the SearchBar is visible. I can see it, bu when I write anything, what I have wrote doesnt appear in UISearchBar

Answer (score 0):

I have missed the code below in appDelegate , ***applicationDidFinishLauching***

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now the SearchBar is working fine!